# Select multiple item by drag block them

Tags: android, gridview, gesture, touch-event

First, let me tell u that i am stressed out by this, because i don't even know the concept / method name, so i can't even search it in google as i don't know the keywords, but ill try my best to explain it. Feel free to modify my contents and title as you see fit.

what i want to achieve is this:
i have view group contains many child views, or it can be GridView i want to able to block select some of it child views, and return the selected / blocked items.

pictures worth more than thousands words:
[image]

any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I used the keyword "box select" to Google such feature.

I am not sure what is the specific implementation for Android, but there is plenty of implementation for web / browser, e.g. [select.js](https://github.com/Simonwep/selection)

The gist is to loop through all "elements" and check whether the element falls into the the "box select" area.